# How can I convert json into xml, if that json is in xml tag?

Tags: json, xml

[{"$$hashKey":"object:982","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:983","c1":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c2":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c5":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c4":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c3":{"val":1,"cclass":"active"},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:984","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:985","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:986","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:987","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:988","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}},{"$$hashKey":"object:989","c1":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c2":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c0":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c6":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c5":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c4":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c3":{"val":0,"cclass":""},"c7":{"val":0,"cclass":""}}]

Comment: HI, above is my json which I am getting inside a xml tag. Now I want to convert this json into xml.

Comment: Quite easy: `json2xml(jsonString)`.

Comment: Firstly I suspect it isn't inside an XML tag, it is most likely between two tags (a start tag and an end tag). Secondly, which part is causing you difficulty: extracting a string from the content of an XML element, or converting a JSON string into XML?